# Is it a good practice to use no_errors_schema in Angular 9 apps?

Tags: angular

I want to use content projection feature in my app, and when I applied the selectors and attributes in my templates, the app has show nothing and in chrome's console window I have this `Uncaught Error: Template parse errors`.
with a little search I find out that if I use `no_error_schema` from `angular/core` in my `app.module.ts` as below:

```
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
```

then error has gone away and the app working properly.
now my question is, is it a good practice for resolving this issue or not? and if not what is the best way to use content projection in angular 9 apps ?

Answer (score -1):

The NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA tells the Angular compiler to ignore unrecognized elements and attributes.
if you are not that much care about app performance and ok with empty tags which come at compilation time, then you can use it,
Else, you will remove it and resolve error for improve app performance.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but this has nothing to do with performance, its more about validating that the tags are correct...